# Cómo convertir código html,css ,js en apk?

Tags: javascript, html, css, indexeddb

Buenas pues mi duda es como convertir mi código html, css y js en apk teniendo bajos recursos, en mi caso Vi que se podía hacer con Cordova y otros soportes pero de inmediato en los tutoriales que ví piden Android studio cosa que mi pc no soporta, en otro caso Vi que se logra con una aplicación llamada website2apk que si bien cumple, por algún motivo cuando la trabajo con indexedDB ignora mi código de editar registros (literalmente es como si saltará la línea sin importar como lo ajusto)

Hay alguna manera de hacerlo para PC de bajos recursos o alguna manera de que la aplicación mencionada trabaje sin problemas con indexedDB?

Comment: Si o si necesitas el `Android Development Kit` ya que si dices que no puedes usar android studio entonces hay opciones un tanto mas livianas pero te demorarias siglos compilando el programa cada vez, el android development kit lo puedes sacar de manera sencilla desde android studio, sin embargo si solo necesitas ese paquete sin tener que instalar android studio la pagina oficial te provee una forma de descargar este paquete desde la terminal usando `command tools`, una alternativa que puedes usar es ya sea `flutter` o `ionic` por ejemplo.

Comment: En mi experiencia propia nunca he usado `flutter`, pero ultimamente se ha hecho muy popular, mientras que para el caso de ionic, si que lo he usado, pero al parecer ya se esta haciendo obsoleto y sus modulos parecen comenzar a tener problemas de seguridad, `ionic` te permite elegir entre varios frameworks como angular, react y vue, y ademas te permite integrar compositor.

Comment: y si usas Progressive Web Apps, con eso no dependes de un compilador

Comment: Sorry, en vez de compositor quice decir capacitor.

Comment: Solución corta: Usa [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/)

Answer (score 3):

Kaixo.

Yo soy nuevo y ayer me hice la misma pregunta, y se me ocurrio la siguiente solución simple y barata (para principiantes como yo, o alumnos de ESO): se puede convertir html+css+js+png+svg a una apk con MIT App inventor. (Los pros se reirán)

Vamos a utilizar el MIT App Inventor como compilador web gratuito. La apk generada hace de servidor web+Web viewer de nuestro código.

(Me salto las explicaciones de cómo registrarse en MIT App Inventor.)

1-)Se hace un nuevo proyecto.

2-)Se añade un webviewer,En la url del webviewer http:/localhost/index.html

3-) En media (a la derecha) los archivos html, js y css, png, etc.. sin subcarpetas.

4-) Ajustar las propiedades de Screen1.

5-) Compilar y descargar la apk.

0-)Recomiendo familiarizarse con MIT AI Companion, para los ajustes finales y "depuración". (Para evitar compilar infinidad de veces)

Apache Cordova, y otras mil variantes más modernas se me quedan grandes a mi, y seguiria sin poder generar y probar para iOS, ya que no tengo un MAC.

Seguramente MIT app inventor compile para iOS antes de que yo tenga un MAC y un iPhone.

Agur bero bat.